# Best practice for validating a URL with Spring-MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC for my web application.
I need to validate that the URL the user inputs is valid and was wondering if there is something in Spring that can do the basic checks for me (for example starts with http/https, has domain name etc).

ValidationUtils only contains very basic checks and I know I can write a regular expression in the validate() method however prefer to avoid it inm case someone has already done it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up using `UrlValidator` from **apache commons**.

Comment: This isn't spring mvc solution.

Answer (score 9):

In the past, I have always utilized [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html). Simply annotate the appropriate field in your form bean with a [`@URL`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.html) constraint.

If you've never used the ORM part of Hibernate before, don't let that scare you. The Validator portion is not dependent on the ORM stuff, and integrating it into Spring is [very straightforward](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-validation-example.html).

If for some reason you can't use Hibernate Validator... or you just want to stick with what you're comfortable with, a good place for regex's is RegExLib.com; several patterns that can match a URI [are listed there](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=1&categoryId=2).

Comment: So basically what you're saying is, Spring doesn't have a URL validator. What if we aren't using Hibernate and instead using MyBatis?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I just need the same and I think I'll go with the **PropertyEditors** in SpringFramework.

More precisely there is **URLEditor**, which you can use to convert a String representation to an actual URL object.

Here is a link to the respective documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beans-conversion

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/URLEditor.html

In my case, I think about using the following code within a Spring Validator to check whether a String entered by a user is a valid URL or not:

```
try {
    PropertyEditor urlEditor = new URLEditor();
    urlEditor.setAsText(field.getValue());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    errors.rejectValue("nameOfTheFieldToBeValidated", "url_is_invalid");
}
```

However, as for now, I'm unsure whether it is possible to configure which protocol is going to be accepted as valid (i.e. URLEditor seems to also accept URLs starting with "classpath:")

Comment: Ok, just to let you know, I too use UrlValidator from apache commons.

Answer (score -1):

Use a spring interceptor:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-interceptors-your

Comment: As far as I understand Spring interceptor allows you to modify the HttpRequest and HttpResponse. Of you course you could apply URL validity checks there but if that's the case I prefer using the Validator interface. My question was more about if there's something in Spring that can validate the URL for me instead of me using messy regexp. Something like "The Awnry Bear" has shown above with Hibernate only with pure Spring.

Comment: This is really bad and this is misuse of a spring interceptor, this isn't its use case.