# SpringMVC valadation URL link

Tags: java, url, bean-validation, spring-validator, url-validation

How can I do URL validation from my site? For example, if a user accesses one URL link like "mysite.com", he proceeds to the web page. However, if he try another URL like "mysite.com/what", I what to show an error message, and tell him this like is not valid.

I've tried this method, but it don't work and *UrlValidator* is deprecated: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-validate-url-in-java/

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to re-phrase your question. Do you want to validate links of your own site, or does your app needs to validate arbitrary external links which when valid you are forwarding to? If the latter, note that there is a big difference between syntactically correct URLs and actually accessible URLs. The latter you can only confirm by trying to request the URL.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to achieve what you want, each one depends on how "deep" you want to dig and validate your URL: a URL may be syntactically correct but the (sub)domain does not exist. You may need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989454/best-practice-for-validating-a-url-with-spring-mvc) (but you didn't tell us whether you are using Spring Framework) or you can build your own UrlValidator using the [Common Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/UrlValidator.html) version and [Google Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html) together, as we did for instance for email addresses.